# Does there exist a $\lambda$-good, $\omega$-incomplete filter on $\kappa$ such that $P(\kappa)/\lambda$ is $\lambda$-saturated?

Tags: logic, reference-request, set-theory, model-theory, filters

Let $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ be cardinals (we can assume $\lambda < 2^\kappa$).  Does there exist a $\lambda$-good, $\omega$-incomplete filter on $\kappa$ such that the quotient $P(\kappa)/\lambda$, of the powerset Boolean algebra by $\lambda$, is $\lambda$-saturated?  Can such a thing exist when $\lambda = \kappa$?  What set-theoretic assumptions would we need?

The motivation is Shelah's result (*For what filters is every reduced product saturated?*, 1972) saying that such a filter always gives rise to a $\lambda$-saturated reduced product with the index set $\kappa$.  If $\kappa^+ = 2^\kappa$  and $\lambda = \kappa$, then those reduced products are just saturated.

Neither Shelah's paper or those that cite it contained an answer to this question.